# Is there a way I can make squircle the permanent icon shape?

Tags: settings, developer-options, app-icons

Android on my Nokia 6 sets circle as the default app icon shape.  I discovered some time ago how to enable developer mode and switch to squircle, which gives a larger icon surface with more information.

Unfortunately, every time I restart my phone, it defaults back to circle, and I have to manually change it to squircle again.

Is there a way to lock this setting so it won't reset when the phone is reset, so I won't lose my squircles?

Comment: That depends o the used launcher app. I use Nova launcher which allows to select the icon shape persistently.

Comment: I'm just using the default launcher.

Comment: Like Robert said, this depends on the launcher app (though this could also be implemented using icon packs I suppose). Look into your launcher settings. If you don't find what you are looking for then replacing the launcher app is the only way forward.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a launcher.
Nova launcher is a good launcher. But there are more online.

Comment: do you have links to Nova or others that you'd suggest?